# Validate multiple forms without having to have validation code in each form

Tags: c#, forms, validation

I am developing an app in C# which has forms that takes simillar inputs from users at different states.

I need to be able to validate them and for that reason I am using **errorproviders**

The code is working fine but I notice that with my current knowledge if I wanted to validate multiple forms then I will have to keep copy pasting the validation code for similar forms all over in each of them, I am wondering if there is a simpler way of reusing the validation code by having it in a central location that can be accessed by all of the forms instead of having to code it for each of them.

Below is a snippet of the validation code, in C#

```
//Methods to verify and user inputs
        private bool ValidateName()
        {
            bool bStatus = true;
            if (name.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                errorProvider2.SetError(name, "");
                errorProvider1.SetError(name, "Please Enter Name");
                bStatus = false;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(name, "");
                errorProvider2.SetError(name, "Good");
                bstatus = true;
            }
            return bStatus;
        }
        private void name_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            ValidateName();
        }
```

What I want to be able to do is have the method **ValidateName()** defined in such a way that I could just call it in the **name_Validating()** function of forms which has a textbox called name to validate it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like what you'll want is to basically call the `ValidateName()` with some parameters, so you can reuse the code (assuming that the only difference is the params you pass).

Comment: yes that is what I want to do I want to be able to reuse the code, but I am not sure how to do it any ideas?

Comment: what are the things that change, and how ?

Comment: The name of the textboxes might get changed, say in form1 i have the text box that gets the user's name, named as "name" in the 2nd form i could have it named as "username" but if that is going to be an issue I can use the same name for any textbox, that accepts username through out the app

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something along these lines. Not in front of a project so don't have the precise syntax though. It should point you in the right direction though

```
//Methods to verify and user inputs
private bool ValidateName(string aName)
{
    bool bStatus = true;
    // You'll need to fill this bit
    // cast or instatiate a textbox here, let's call it txt_box_name
    // 
    // cast : if you pass an object that you know is a textbox 
    // 
    // instantiate : you can create an instance of a textbox with Activator.CreateInstance
    //   more on that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
    //   
    //  and then continue as normal with your generic text box field
    if (txt_box_name.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
    return bStatus;
}
private void name_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateName("name");
    // or :
    //ValidateName("username");
}
```

Comment: I had tried this but the issue is where do i place this code? Do i put them on a seperate class? I tried that before posting the question in here, got errors ...

Comment: Depends. the callback for the button click is usually in the code behind, so you can do it there. Otherwise, you'll have to put it in a place that the codebehind can access in order to fire that method.